# Custom migrate with cross database joins issue

Tags: migrations, database

I'm facing an issue when running cross-database joins whilst implementing a custom module using Drupal Migrate.

The set up: I have 2 databases: `myshop_migrate` - the migrate db and `myshop` - the Drupal db.  Each database is located on separate AWS instances - so migrate db is not locally available.

I have the following set up in settings.php - I can confirm this works, connection occurs >>

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'my_shop',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '******',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);

$databases['migrateserver']['default'] = array (
      'database' => 'myshop_migrate',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '******',
      'host' => '12.34.56.78',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
);
```

In my custom migrate module, I'm utilising `db_set_active('migrateserver');` before running a `$query` to switch the db prior.

## Example 1 - This works:

```
 db_set_active('migrateserver');
$query = db_select('myshop_migrate.product_commerce', 'p')
             ->fields('p', array('sku', 'ref', 'colorcode', 'size', 'title',
                'product_group', 'user1', 'user2', 'sup_ref', 'price', 'prev_price',
                'vat', 'rem',
             ));
    $query->leftJoin('myshop_migrate.stock_commerce', 's', "s.newref = p.sku");
    $query->fields('s', array('stock'));

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
    db_set_active();
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationEntityAPI('commerce_product', 'product');
```

## Example 2 - This doesn't work

```
db_set_active('migrateserver');
   $query = db_select('myshop_migrate.stock_commerce', 's')
          ->fields('s', array('ref'));
    $query->addExpression('MAX(s.last_modified)', 'last_modified');

   db_set_active();
    $query->innerJoin('myshop.commerce_product', 'p', "s.newref = p.sku");
    $query->addExpression('COUNT(p.sku)', 'cnt');
    $query->addField('p', 'status');
    $query->having('COUNT(p.sku) = 0');

   db_set_active('migrateserver');
    $query->groupBy('s.ref');

    $this->highwaterField = array(
      'name' => 'last_modified', // Column to be used as highwater mark
      'alias' => 's',           // Table alias containing that column
    );
    // Note that it is important to process rows in the order of the highwater mark
    $query->orderBy('last_modified');
   db_set_active();
```

Example 2 does not work, I don't know how to solve this. The query doesn't run (like it does it example 1) - the error I receive is as follows:

> MigrateException: Failure to sort migration list - most likely due to circular dependencies involving..

I've looked at a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414295/cross-database-table-joins-in-drupal - but prefixes do not seem to work.

Comment: [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) states that you should avoid asking questions where there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”. If you already know solution and all you want to ask is "Anyone faced something similar?", then you shouldn't ask it on Drupal Answers. If you have some technical question about Drupal, please make clear what is it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, is that better? I should have been more to the point.  I've no clue how to fix this problem I'm facing in example 2 - tried to provide as much information as possible around what I'm trying to achieve - hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Looks better now :)

Comment: The Q you linked to says Drupal doesn't support single queries across multiple DBs. Can you split the query into two (one for each DB)?

Comment: `$query = db_select` that-s the point where active database gets saved inside query object that is now in `$query`. Changing it later have no effect on `$query`. I'm afraid @Andy is right and 2 queries are the only reliable way.

Comment: By running 2 separate queries - how can I apply joins between the 2 dbs?